# Installation Error - Redirect loop(Magento 1.9.0.1)

Tags: error, redirect, install, installation

I had parked **http: //example.com/** domain to a sub folder in my server lets say it "/magentofolder"
I want to install magento inside /magentofolder. so far I did,

1)Unzipped magento installation file.

2)Moved all magento files to the root directory, in this case the root directory for the domain
**http: //example.com** is /magentofolder

when I open http: //example.com it enters into a redirect loop(302) between

**http: //example.com/index.php/install** and **http: //example.com/magentofolder/index.php/install**

unable to continue the installation, any help regarding this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Before copying any files into your folder, you can make sure the files on that folder can be accessed.

This can be done by having an index.php file on the specified folder, let's say you have `/root_folder/your_magento_subfolder` that is served for  `http://example.com/subfolder` URL . Add/Overwrite the /root_folder/your_magento_subfolder/index.php file with just this content:

```
<php echo "foo"; exit; ?>
```

And try to access: `http://example.com/subfolder`. You should see a white page with `foo` ;

By having this set you can move forward to replace your modified index.php with the one from the magento install folder and start your install.

Comment: Tried as you suggested, when I point to http://example.com it don't work! if I point to http://example.com/index.php/ 
the content in the echo statement is displayed

Comment: may be there is some problem with htaccess file, facing hard time in figuring out the solution

Comment: Then on the same folder with index.php you also must have .htaccess file that comes with the magento install files.
`MAGENTO_FOLDER/.htaccess`