# redirect loop on installation

Tags: upgrade, php-5.4, installation, upgrade-script

Midst installation it has decided to crop up with the error:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I have attempted to delete var/cache and var/session but still the error is there. Checked permissions and files: all files present and right permissions. If I delete local.xml then the error goes until I have inputted the information in the configuration section of the installation again and pressed next, then the that error reappears?

My question is different as for one I have been through al the points in the step there yet still no cause identified, also my issue occurs in middle of installation process, not after!

If it help, the server has the OS centos 7 and Apache. The server is a new dell poweredge.

Also, when I previously attempted an upgrade, I came across this same error and overcame it by running the db repair tool, but in hindsight I believe this is not a valid solution as the installation is still in mid installation and running the repair tool will give an incorrect installation and possible huge errors later on.

[Installation Error - Redirect loop(Magento 1.9.0.1)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37293/installation-error-redirect-loopmagento-1-9-0-1?rq=1)

Tried that in hope again still no luck!!!! I shall go down the database repair root if I cannot get this sorted soon, as I believe I have done everything that I can and that being my only solution.

UPDATE:

This has to be a database issue, using same copy of files I managed to install onto a fresh new database. So, this redirect loop error is being caused by something in the database, which I need to figure out now?

What could cause a redirect loop in db ?

Tried looking for the web/base_url_redirect field in core_config_data but no such field exists.

Comment: Try opening your browser in incognito mode, Chrome has been known to cache stuff like this for me in the past

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews I just tried that in hope but sadly no luck still got this error. Very much annoying me.

Comment: @Elias Mine is to do with installation, occuring during the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Check the url configs in `core_config_data` table. Also check whether `.htaccess` looks ok.

Comment: kumar I have checked those and it is only mid way through installation this error happens. htaccess will be the new one that comes with a fresh new copy of a magento download. I have not modified the .htaccess file.